# Constraining a record type during port/signal declaration

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I want to define a record type like this :

```
package my_package is
    type natural_array is array (NATURAL RANGE <> ) of natural_sub;
    type floating_point is 
        record 
            sign     : integer range -1 to 1;
            mantissa : natural_array;   --I am asking about this;
            exponent : integer range -50 to 50; 
        end record;
end my_package;
```

and want to use the type in my module for declaration like this:

```
entity arithematic_unit is
Port (
    a_in: in floating_point(3 downto 0);  --want to define mantissa length here
    b_in : in floating_point(3 downto 0); 
    op: in natural range 1 to 7; 
    c_out : out floating_point(7 downto 0)  );
end arithematic_unit;
```

How can I do this? 
I am using vivado webpack 2013.4 version.

Comment: The name of the record element is missing in the constraint. I don't think that any Vivado version supports this feature.

Comment: @JHBonarius I would like to know more about the synthesizability of datatypes. 'They are not properly supported' means what? you mean that it depends on the tool we use? Here to create record, I have used only integers and natural numbers which can be synthesized.

Comment: The subtype indication for the interface object declarations should provide a record constraint (-2008) where each unconstrained record element is provided with a record element constraint, e.g. `b_in: in floating_point (mantissa (3 downto 0));` See IEEE Std 1076-2008 5.3.3 Record types, 6.3 Subtype declarations and 6.5.2 Interface object declarations. No mention of support for *record element constraints* or *record elements* in any version of UG901 (Synthesis) Supported VHDL-2008 Features. The question is not specific and lacks detectable research effort despite being up voted.

Comment: @JHBonarius fully constrained record types are supported by latest versions of ISE, Vivado, and Quartus. What tools are there that don't support them?

Comment: Prior to -2008 element subtypes were supplied by the element subtype definition (a subtype indication) in a record type declaration. IEEE Std 1076-2002 4.2 Subtype declarations "If the subtype indication does not include a constraint, the subtype is the same as that denoted by the type mark" albeit natural range arrays  are not useful. Vivado 2014.3 UG 901 requires "fully constrained array types", presumably record elements of array types as well. Record types are supported, although not in interface objects for mixed language models (UG900, Simulation). -2008 support is from Vivado 2015.3.

Comment: -2008 support is from Vivado 2015.3 where UG901 mentions unconstrained element types are supported. The question is whether or not a record element constraint is supported in an object declaration's subtype indication. See [Arrays/Records with unconstrained elements (2008)](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/Arrays-Records-with-unconstrained-elements-2008/td-p/755647) (simulation) asked in March 2017, meshing with Paebbel's comment. You'd think vendors weren't participating in the standard revision process or something. Oh, wait...

Comment: @scary_jeff I just remember that somewhere back in 2008(?) I had some problems with record types. Haven't used them since. So good that the support has improved.

Comment: @user1155120 maybe companies like Altera should instead propose their own hardware description language, and call it AHDL or so ;)

Comment: @JHBonarius It's been almost 10 years and there's not one tool compliant with the -2008 standard. P1076.8 (ICL's VHDL+ SDL) quit about the time SystemVerilog appeared. There's SystemC and HLS, multi-language simulators (along with their patents), verification frameworks. Vendors are more than happy to have market capture enforced by patents or difficulty moving to a competitors methodology. VHDL isn't making or breaking marketing paradigms.

Comment: @user1155120 I know. It has been bothering me too. My comment was meant as a joke ;). But you're right, it's no laughing matter.